# React - clear router links, is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, router

i have a welcome page App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import About from './components/About';
import Datas from './components/Datas';
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <h1 className="text-center">Todo List App</h1>
            <Grid>
              <Row className="show-grid">
                <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={6} md={4}>
                  <ul className="list-group">
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                      <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                      <Link to="/datas">Datas</Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </Col>
                <Col xsHidden md={4}>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Grid>

            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/datas" component={Datas} />
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

But when i go to Login and after successfull login want to go to dashboard, i want that links /login, /about and /datas dissapear. Is it possible? Beacuase every new file js which i will create inherit Router links etc. Please about help/hints

Comment: You can use conditionally render the Link tag using a ternary.
`{isLoggedIn ? null : <Link to="/login">Login</Link>}`
Where isLoggedIn is a prop that indicates that there is a valid session

Comment: How to pass props from components to up? By <Route ... ?

Comment: Well you just need to have that "isLoggedIn" boolean somewhere, you can use local state, or a state management library like redux.

`constructor() {
    this.state = { isLoggedIn : false }
}`

I'm assuming in your Login component you will have a submit. In that you can have a callback which sets "isLoggedIn" to be true.

`handleLogIn() {
  this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
}`

Comment: Ok so better will be using i think Redux? Because otherwise i must to pass props from one component to another?

Comment: Redux can be overkill, theres a good amount of boilerplate to write. If you are expanding on this project and adding more features. You will be interacting with a good amount of data across different pages/components. So yes redux will be helpful then. But for the purpose of the question you can use local state to test it.